# Should the expected value be hard-coded into the Assert

Tags: .net, unit-testing, conventions, nunit

My own personal preference would be to use a variable, but maybe there are reasons against this?  I haven't been able to find any resources that state the pros or cons of using one of these over the other.

Option 1:

```
[TestClass]
public PersonAgeTest
{
  [Test]
  public void GetFullNameWithPrefix_Parameterless_ReturnsValueWithPrefix
  {
    // Arrange
    var person = new person(Gender.Male);
    var person.LastName = "Philips";
    var expected = "Mr. Philips";

    // Act
    var actual = person.GetSalutation(); 

    // Assert
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
[TestClass]
public PersonAgeTest
{
  [Test]
  public void GetFullNameWithPrefix_Parameterless_ReturnsValueWithPrefix
  {
    // Arrange
    var person = new person(Gender.Male);
    var person.LastName = "Philips";

    // Act
    var actual = person.GetSalutation(); 

    // Assert
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo("Mr. Philips"));
  }
}
```

Maybe it's too minor of a difference?  I'm not sure, it seems better to ask.

Comment: I personally prefer to use the [TestCase] where the input and expected outputs are all passed as arguments to the test function, whenever possible.

Comment: Ok, wow, using NUnit for the first time, and that seems completely the right direction.  Assuming I can't use the TestCaseAttribute... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I personally prefer to use the [TestCase] where the input and expected outputs are all passed as arguments to the test function, whenever possible:

```
[TestClass]
public class PersonAgeTest
{
    [TestCase("Philips","Mr. Phillips")]  
    public void GetFullNameWithPrefix_SimpleValue_ReturnsValueWithPrefix(string input, string expected)
      {
          // Arrange
          var person = new person(Gender.Male);
          var person.LastName = input;

          // Act
          var actual = person.GetSalutation();

          // Assert
          Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
      }
}
```

There is even a way to also do some sort of specified return value as your TestCase arguments in the case of NUnit, but I don't remember off the top of my head how that works or what it's syntax is.

In situations where you can't or it isn't appropriate to pass your inputs and outputs in as parameters, I would define them all up front so you can quickly eyeball what you are feeding to your test. I have been burned plenty of times debugging stuff due to a failing test case, only to find a typo in my input. Grouping all that together makes things easier to deal with.

Comment: It would look like `[TestCase("Philips", Result = "Mr. Philips")]` and `return actual;`.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to find an edge case where I wouldn't want to use the TestCaseAttribute, but it seems like an insanely proficient way to create tests.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: nothing is going to work for everything, but use what's appropriate for the task at hand. TestCase won't work in situations where you are testing the behavior of a particular class over time, such as state machines, for example.